# #include errors detected Linux

Tags: c++, c, include, include-path, vcpkg

I work on a crypt and decrypt tool and i got an error about library :

```
#include <gcrypt.h>
```

all the other library without errors just this one and when i peek the problem he show me this :

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit.C/C++(1696)
cannot open source file "gpg-error.h" (dependency of "gcrypt.h")C/C++(1696)
```

Also he show me a Quick fix like installing VCPKG and i do it and nothing work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. find the `gpg-error.h` file. Remember the path.
2. IF(NOT FOUND) {you need to find it on internet. IF(FOUND) { Copy it to the directory of your choice. Remember the directory} ELSE GOTO ERROR}
3. Add -I{dirrectory where the file is located} to your gcc command line options. ENJOY. EXIT.

ERROR. Email the program author and ask for the file. WAIT.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should find the header on your machine. And after that "tell" OS to use a path to it for your app.

Comment: I find the same issue in a forum and a user told this step but nothing Work!

Comment: @YasserTH so, we need more info about the problem. WHEN u got an error outputs. And how did u tried to solve it already